# Holomorphic function with Taylor coefficients that tend to 0

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. If we can write $F(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ for $z \in \mathbb{D}$, then why does $a_{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Uniform continuity of $f$ shows that $\lim_{r \rightarrow 1^{-}}f(rz) = f(z)$ uniformly for $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Observe that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^{2}\, d\theta = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}|a_{j}|^{2}r^{2j}.$$ Letting $r \rightarrow 1^{-}$ on both sides gives $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(e^{i\theta})|^{2}\, d\theta = \lim_{r \rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}|a_{j}|^{2}r^{2j}.$$ If I could interchange limit and sum on the right hand side, then $\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}|a_{j}|^{2} < \infty$ and hence $a_{j} \rightarrow 0$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$. However, I don't know how to justify the interchange of sum and limit.

Comment: $r\mapsto r^{2j}$ is monotonically increasing. The monotone convergence theorem allows the interchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that for all $r < 1$,
$$
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}|a_{j}|^{2}r^{2j} \le L := \lim_{t \rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}|a_{j}|^{2}t^{2j}
$$
From this you see that all partial sums satisfy
$$
\sum_{j = 0}^{N}|a_{j}|^{2}r^{2j} \le L
$$
Now by continuity of each partial sum as a function of $r$, you see that
$$
\sum_{j = 0}^{N}|a_{j}|^{2} = \sum_{j = 0}^{N}|a_{j}|^{2}1^{2j} \le L
$$
These partial sums are bounded above and are monotonically increasing, so the series $\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}|a_{j}|^{2}$ converges. This means it's Cauchy, and so the terms tend to zero.